# How to get sum of all td's that comes dynamically in php?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, sum

> I am having one html table and fetching rows dynamically in foreach
>   loop. I am adding one tfooter to display sum of all rows.but its not
>   calculating right amounts. I am using += operator in foreach loop for
>   particular variables.

```
foreach ($getRangeYear as $value) 
        {
            // my query to fetch records that gives proper result
            $results1       =   mysqli_query($link,$Records1);
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($results1);
            $TOTAL_AMOUNT1 = $row1['AMOUNT1'] + $row1['AMOUNT2'];
            $RECEIVED_AMOUNT1 =$row1['AMOUNT1'] + $row1['AMOUNT2'];
            $PENDING_AMOUNT1 = $TOTAL_AMOUNT1 - $RECEIVED_AMOUNT1;
            $tableOutput .="<td>".number_format($TOTAL_AMOUNT1,2)."</td>
                        <td>".number_format($RECEIVED_AMOUNT1,2)."</td>
                        <td>".number_format($PENDING_AMOUNT1,2)."</td>";    
        };
```

As you can see above code i am having one foreach loop that iterates till he gets years within form.
Suppose user will select 2017 To 2019 then loop will goes 3 times.
I am populating my data in table structure.

```
| 2017                     |   2018                |            2019           |
Total | Received | Pending |Total|Received|Pending |Total | Received | Pending |
```

As you can see in my loop I am getting `$TOTAL_AMOUNT1` ,  `$RECEIVED_AMOUNT1`, `$PENDING_AMOUNT1`. 
And I am getting proper results for each year.

Now i want to display sum of each rows. So i create one tfooter. and create another foreach loop :

```
//tfooter
        foreach ($getRangeYear as $value) 
            {       

                $TOTAL_AMOUNT1 += $row1['AMOUNT1'] + $row1['AMOUNT2'];
                $RECEIVED_AMOUNT1 +=$row1['AMOUNT1'] + $row1['AMOUNT2'];
                $PENDING_AMOUNT1 += $TOTAL_AMOUNT1 - $RECEIVED_AMOUNT1;
                $tableOutput .= "<th>".$TOTAL_AMOUNT1."</th>
                <th>".$RECEIVED_AMOUNT1."</th>
                <th>".$PENDING_AMOUNT1."</th>";
            };
```

I am using here += operator to get sum of all rows but its not working.please help me with the same.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to amswer it. Also: "its not working" is not helpful. Can you tell us what actually happens, and what you want to happen? That being said: It is better to sum the values of each "row" when you're creating the "rows". (I think you mean "columns" instead of "rows")

Comment: not working means it shows inproper results. not adding all columns.

Comment: if i am having only@KIKOSoftware if i am having only one year then it shows me proper sum of all columns if its more than 1 year then its not showing proper sum in tfooter